# Adding ActionListener to JRadioButton & JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jradiobutton, itemlistener

So what I am trying to achieve here is, if the first radio button and the first option from the first combobox is selected then I want to display the food under that category, if it is first radio button and the second option from the first combobox then some other food under that category. I got the radiobutton part working fine but not able to get the dropdown part along with it. The line rb1.isSelected() && cmbItems[0].isSelected() is giving me the error. Please help me overcome the error. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tryout extends JFrame  implements ActionListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        private JPanel inputpanel;
        private JPanel searchpanel;
        public JButton submit;
        public JRadioButton rb1, rb2;
        public JComboBox <String> cmb;
        public String cmbItems [] ={"North Indian","South Indian","East Indian", "West Indian"};
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Get selected JRadioButton");  

        public Tryout() {           
                inputpanel = createPage1();
                searchpanel = createPage2();
                tabbedPane.addTab("Input Form", inputpanel);
                tabbedPane.addTab("Search Form", searchpanel);
                this.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);           
        }

        public JPanel createPage1() {           
            String cmbItems2 [] ={"European","Asian","American"};          
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            //Column1
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            c.weightx = 0.5;
            c.weighty = 0.5;
            JLabel region = new JLabel("Enter Region");      
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            panel.add(region, c);
            JLabel subregion = new JLabel("Enter Sub-Region");
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            panel.add(subregion, c);
            //Column2
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            rb1 = new JRadioButton("Indian"); 
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 0;
            bg.add(rb1);
            panel.add(rb1, c);
            cmb = new JComboBox<String>(cmbItems);
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;   
            panel.add(cmb, c);        
            //Column3
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            rb2 = new JRadioButton("International");
            c.gridx = 2;
            c.gridy = 0;           
            bg.add(rb2);
            panel.add(rb2, c);          
            JComboBox<String> cmb2 = new JComboBox<String>(cmbItems2);
            c.gridx = 2;
            c.gridy = 1;      
            cmb2.setEnabled(false);
            panel.add(cmb2, c); 
            submit = new JButton("Submit");
            c.weighty = 10;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 2;
            panel.add(submit, c);
            submit.addActionListener(this);           
            return panel;            
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==submit) {
                if(rb1.isSelected() && cmbItems[0].isSelected()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"You select : "+rb1.getText());
                }
                else if(rb2.isSelected()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"You select : "+rb2.getText());
                }               
            }           
        }

        public JPanel createPage2() {           
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
                JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
                panel.add(field);
                JButton search = new JButton("SEARCH");
                panel.add(search);
                return panel;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                Tryout ex = new Tryout();
                                ex.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                ex.setSize(500,500);
                                ex.setVisible(true);
                        }
                });
        }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmbItems` is an array of strings, so naturally it wouldn't know anything about whether it's "selected." You want to ask the combobox itself what the selected item is, so you should say

```
if(rb1.isSelected() && cmb.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"You select : "+rb1.getText());
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I have one more thing to ask you. What I am also trying to do is, keep both the ComboBox disabled, when Indian is selected I want the dropdown corresponding to Indian to be enabled and on clicking the button, show the relevant message.

Comment: add an `ActionListener` to both radio buttons. For the "Indian" ActionListener, enable the combobox with `cmb.setEnabled(true)`. For the "International" ActionListener, disable the combobox with `cmb.setEnabled(false)`. You also might want to disable the combobox when the GUI loads initially

Comment: I can't get you completely, a small example would help.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Z3dqjwDN
Also, you'll have to make cmb2 final or it won't compile

Comment: GOT it :) I did using another way with the help of your hint. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: I am having trouble adding images now. I dragged the image into the package and added this code. ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("pic.JPG"));
                JLabel li = new JLabel(img); 
                panel.add(li);